# Default Language in Itunes Preview?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

Hello everyone i have an iphone app which i specified the Default Language as French when creating the app in itunes connect. I have set the Development native region as France in the app.plist file. The app is approved but still the "Default language" on the itunes preview page is English.
Any help will be highly appreciated :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. But in my case, I did not set the Localizations key/value in the properties list. Everywhere in iTunes Connect it says German, but on the iTunes Preview page it says Language: English.
Should I upload a new version or ..?

Answer (score 0):

From Apple, https://developer.apple.com/app-store/app-previews/

> If you submit app previews they will appear in all countries where
>   your app is available. However, you may only submit a single set of
>   app previews designed for iPhone, iPod touch, and iPad in one language
>   localization.